# Trying to load urls in the same tab. Can it be done:

Tags: google-chrome, command-line-arguments

Is it possible to open the second link: "Link2" in the same tab from the previous link? The current Batch script opens a new tab for the second link. I want to open the second link in the same tab as the first one.

```
timeout /t 10
start "Chrome" "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 4" https://link1.com
timeout /t 20
start "Chrome" "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 4" https://link2.com
exit
```

Didn't find a solution yet